# Symfony2 set up

Tags: symfony, php, suhosin, phar

I'm trying to set up sample Symfony2 project as shown here 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html

and after accessing config.php I have this:

```
Major problems have been detected and must be fixed before continuing:
Add "phar" to suhosin.executor.include.whitelist in php.ini*.
```

I added this:

```
suhosin.executor.include.whitelist="phar"
```

into php.ini, but config.php still show the same message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Check that you edited the correct php.ini, usually a PHP installation has several php.ini (one for CGI, one for CLI, one for APACHE2). Have a look in `/etc/php5` for instance.

2) Check in phpinfo() that the parameter is taken in account.

3) Refer to this blog post: 
[[Solved] symfony 2 Major problems Major problems have been detected and must be fixed before continuing: Add “phar” to suhosin.executor.include.whitelist in php.ini*.](http://www.nitesh.com.np/php/solved-symfony-2-major-problems-major-problems-have-been-detected-and-must-be-fixed-before-continuing-add-phar-to-suhosin-executor-include-whitelist-in-php-ini/)

The post suggests ensuring suhosin is installed with

```
sudo apt-get install php5-suhosin
```

Comment: What does phpinfo() says about suhosin include whitelist ?

Comment: it's standart php.ini, I didn't change anything

Comment: Where did you add `suhosin.executor.include.whitelist="phar"` then ?

Comment: I mean this is the only thing I've added there

Comment: Then your php.ini is probably not correctly configured................ And it's not - anymore - the standard php.ini.

Comment: Check the `suhosin.executor.include.whitelist` is not there twice in the php.ini

Comment: And check in phpinfo() that you're editing the correct php.ini file.

Comment: php.ini is correct, and suhosin.executor.include.whitelist is not twice there.

Comment: Check suhosin is installed, like he does here : http://www.nitesh.com.np/php/solved-symfony-2-major-problems-major-problems-have-been-detected-and-must-be-fixed-before-continuing-add-phar-to-suhosin-executor-include-whitelist-in-php-ini/

Comment: thank you, that helped. Why did symphony ask for whitelist, when suhosin is not even installed?

Comment: Maybe this is a Symfony dependency or something like that depending on the OS of the server. I don't know for sure.

Comment: +1 to you - sudo apt-get install php5-suhosin did it for me. Have amended the answer to make this clear.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

What you did is right, as skonsoft says you should check if you have installed suhosin and then add "phar" in your php.ini OR conf.d/suhosin.ini

I did this too and the problem persisted

I found the solution [here](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=44936), it was a problem with my libxml2 library

> I have now solved this.
>
> Tracked it down to a libxml2 incompatibility.
>
> Seems that
>   /vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php
>   doesn't like libxml2-2.6.22. An upgrade to 2.8.0 has fixed it - with
>   the required PHP recompile to pick up the new libxml2.
>
> Hope this helps someone!

I'm using Debian 6

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and had to restart following:

/etc/init.d/php-fcgi-vhost-name restart

to get ini line change visible

Answer (score 0):

After installing suhosin package for php,

```
sudo apt-get install php5-suhosin
```

For cli, add in **suhosin.ini** and not php.ini, in debian, under: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/suhosin.ini

```
suhosin.executor.include.whitelist="phar"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this problem in a cPanel server. What i did is:

- reinstalled suhosin using cPanel script /scripts/phpextensionmgr uninstall PHPSuHosin; /scripts/phpextensionmgr install PHPSuHosin
- If the installation was correct then you will get something like

```
find . -name \*.gcno -o -name \*.gcda | xargs rm -f
find . -name \*.lo -o -name \*.o | xargs rm -f
find . -name \*.la -o -name \*.a | xargs rm -f 
find . -name \*.so | xargs rm -f
find . -name .libs -a -type d|xargs rm -rf
find . -name \*.1 | xargs rm -f
rm -f libphp.la   modules/* libs/*
SuHosin extension, version suhosin-0.9.36, activated for php version 5.4
```

- Then add

  ```
   suhosin.executor.include.whitelist="phar"
  ```

  into /usr/local/lib/php.ini file
- Restart Apache

It should be fixed..!!!